# how to save xls file as table in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, import-from-excel

I want to save my excel file as table in database using PHP. Is it possible?
I tried like below. But we need to give table name.

```
<html>

<head>
<?php 
   if(isset($_POST["Import"]))
   {
    include 'database.php';
    $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $heading=true;
    if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
    {
        $file = fopen($filename, "r");      
        while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000)) !== FALSE)
        {
            $num = count($emapData);
             echo $num;
            echo $emapData[0];
            //check if the heading row
            if($heading) {
            // unset the heading flag
            $heading = false;
            // skip the loop
            continue;
            }
            $sql = "INSERT into sheet(name,first_name,last_name)     values('$emapData[0]','$emapData[1]','$emapData[2]')";
            $row=mysql_query($sql);
        }
        fclose($file);
        echo 'CSV File has been successfully Imported';
}
else
        echo 'Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File';
    }
    ?>
</head>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" role="form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                                 <label for="exampleInputFile">File Upload</label>
                                 <input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="150">
                                <p class="help-block">
                                        Only Excel/CSV File Import.
                                </p>
                        </div>
                         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="Import" value="Import">Upload</button>
                    </form>
                    </body>
                    </html>
```

Comment: Change <button type="submit" to <input type="submit"

Comment: Your code is about import csv. Use this link http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-read-excel-file-insert-data-into-mysql-database-using-php_609.html

Comment: file missing 'excel_reader2.php'

Comment: Read article carefully.You can download it from here https://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/downloads/list